# How to access specific object fields?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, attributes, associations, ruby-on-rails-5

I am building a basic bare bones social media app right now.

I have a user class and a status class.

For each status, there is a "creater" (a user object) and a "subject" (a user object that the status is about).  I was able to create tags by using the acts_as_taggable_on gem.  What ends up happening is when a user goes to create a post, he/she can select another user from a dropdown menu.  The chosen user's id attribute is then stored.

Now I am trying to link to the chosen User's profile.  This is my code for show statuses on a profile page.

```
    <% if @statuses %>
      <% @statuses.each do |status| %>
        <div class="well">
          <%= status.content %>
          <br></br>

          #link to user who's associated with the tagId
          <%= link_to User.find(status.tag_list).profile_name, user_profile_path(User.find(status.tag_list).profile_name) %>
          <hr />
          <%= link_to time_ago_in_words(status.created_at), status_path(status) %> ago
        </div>
      <% end %>
    <% end%>
```

this is the line where the above code breaks

```
              <%= link_to User.find(status.tag_list).profile_name, user_profile_path(User.find(status.tag_list).profile_name) %>
```

Can anyone help me out with this?

Comment: define "code breaks"

Comment: it's helpful to post the error message

Answer (score 0):

Not surprised this line is failing:

```
<%= link_to User.find(status.tag_list).profile_name, user_profile_path(User.find(status.tag_list).profile_name) %>
```

A couple points:

- It's a little cleaner to separate it onto multiple lines
- I suspect your problem is because you're passing a profile_name to user_profile_path instead of an id, though I can't be certain without seeing your routes.

Try the following:

```
<% profile_user = User.find(status.tag_list) %>
<%= link_to profile_user.profile_name, user_profile_path(profile_user.id) %>
```